# How to overcome the website not able direct view issue after i using iframe function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, iframe

I have a website that I created by Django python and now I want to insert this website that I create by Django into another web portal(another programing language) by using  function and I notice that I not able to direct view my website, the following picture is the output of my website and I need to click the link **Open this content in a new window** to open a new tab now only I can view my website, anyone have any idea to overcome this security issue?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which is delete 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', in Django settings